# Using vue-mention getting this.$scopedSlots.default is not a function error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
// After run "npm why vue"

vue@2.6.12
node_modules/vue
  dev vue@"^2.6.12" from the root project
  vue@"^2.5.17" from vue-carousel@0.18.0
  node_modules/vue-carousel
    vue-carousel@"^0.18.0" from the root project
  vue@"^2.6.12" from vue-code-diff@1.1.0
  node_modules/vue-code-diff
    vue-code-diff@"^1.1.0" from the root project
  vue@"^2.2.6" from vue-kanban@1.8.0
  node_modules/vue-kanban
    vue-kanban@"^1.8.0" from the root project
  peer vue@"^2.6.0" from vue-mention@1.0.0
  node_modules/vue-mention
    vue-mention@"^1.0.0" from the root project
  vue@"^2.5.13" from vue-pjax-adapter@undefined
  node_modules/vue-pjax-adapter
    vue-pjax-adapter@"github:riverskies/vue-pjax-adapter" from the root project
  peer vue@"^2.6.0" from vue-resize@1.0.1
  node_modules/vue-resize
    vue-resize@"^1.0.1" from v-tooltip@2.1.3
    node_modules/v-tooltip
      v-tooltip@"^2.1.3" from the root project
      peer v-tooltip@"^2.0.0" from vue-mention@1.0.0
      node_modules/vue-mention
        vue-mention@"^1.0.0" from the root project
```

I'm using vue-mention and I keep getting this.$scopedSlots.default is not a function error when I implement it my codes.
my vue version is "2.6.12"

```js
<script>
import { Mentionable } from 'vue-mention'

export default {
  components: {
    Mentionable,
  },

  data () {
    return {
      text: '',
      items: [
        {
          value: 'cat',
          label: 'Mr Cat',
        },
        {
          value: 'dog',
          label: 'Mr Dog',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <Mentionable
    :keys="['@']"
    :items="items"
    offset="6"
  >
    <textarea v-model="text"/>
  </Mentionable>
</template>
```

besides I'm getting prop mutated error for both keys and items property.
does anyone have the same issue with vue components like this?
I really need this component in my project.

Comment: Output of `npm why vue` looks good. Deleting my answer as it is not an issue...

Comment: no problem thanks.@MichalLevý

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when using a component with Scoped Slots. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

`<Mentionable>` needs to have something to render. Since 'text' is an empty string, the `<textarea>` does not render, leaving the template slot empty with nothing for Mentionable to work with.
Try setting a conditional v-if="text" in the `<Mentionable>` component to fix this.